# Jest / Vue test utils - Method coming from subcomponent scoped slot - [Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined

Tags: vue.js, testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils, slots

I'm trying to test one of my component which calls a subcomponent (ie. `b-modal`).

My tested component uses scoped slots from `b-modal` to grab the `close()` method from it and attach it to another event listener. Have a look :

```html
// My custom parent component
<template>
    <b-modal>
        <template #modal-header="{close}">
            <h2 class="card-header-title">
                Coordonnées
            </h2>
            <button class="close close-profile text-dark" @click="close">
                <i class="far fa-times" />
            </button>
        </template>
    </b-modal>
</template>
```

In my test, I mount my component like this :

```js
return shallowMount(MyCustomParentComponent, {
    ...options,
    localVue,
    store,
    stubs: [
        "b-modal"
    ],
});
```

My test passes but Jest is throwing `console.error` warnings :

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined
      
      found in
      
      ---> <Anonymous>
             <Root>
```

I guess my `b-modal` subcomponent is not fully mounted (stub, shallowMount) and the `close()` method is not injected.

What can I do ? Should I mock the `close()` method ? Silent the warnings ? Something else ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: have you tried with `mount` instead of `shallowMount` ?

Comment: Yes, `mount` or `shallowmount` never made any difference. They both need the stub to render `b-modal` subcomponent and, in both cases, `close` method is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could customize the stub of `b-modal`, rendering a `modal-header` slot with a mocked `close()`:

```js
it('should call close() on button click', async () => {
  const close = jest.fn()
  const ok = jest.fn()
  const cancel = jest.fn()
  const wrapper = shallowMount(MyModal, {
    stubs: {
      BModal: {
        render(h) {
          return h('div', [
                            this.$scopedSlots['modal-header']?.({close}),
                            this.$scopedSlots['default']?.({ok, cancel})
                          ]
                  )
        }
      }
    }
  });
  await wrapper.find('button.close').trigger('click')
  expect(close).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```